# MySQL Null Root Password Weak Default Configuration Vulnerability

Tags: mysql

I have a VM that is detected with "MySQL Null Root Password Weak Default Configuration Vulnerability". I checked my user table and here is what I get:

multiple root users having super_priv with different hosts. I changed password for root@localhost
but I still have hosts with following names having root user with no password

1. 127.0.0.1
2. "my vm name"
3. ::1
4. %

what does this ::1 and % mean?

I guess changing all the root passwords on these hosts would fix this issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are all documented in the MySQL manual under [Specifying Account Names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/account-names.html) section:

> A host value can be a host name or an IP address (IPv4 or IPv6). The
>   name 'localhost' indicates the local host. The IP address '127.0.0.1'
>   indicates the IPv4 loopback interface. The IP address '::1' indicates
>   the IPv6 loopback interface.
>
> •  The % and _ wildcard characters are permitted in host name or IP
>   address values. These have the same meaning as for pattern-matching
>   operations performed with the LIKE operator. For example, a host value
>   of '%' matches any host name, whereas a value of '%.mysql.com' matches
>   any host in the mysql.com domain. '192.168.1.%' matches any host in
>   the 192.168.1 class C network.

Apart from assigning these user accounts a password, you should also consider if you needed all of these accounts (root@% in particular) and remove those, that are not needed.